# Limit law proof for max

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

I am working towards an extremely difficult real analysis problem. The statement is as follows:

Prove that if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = l$ and $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = m$ then $\lim_{x \to a} \max(f(x), g(x)) = \max(l, m)$ Some definitions:

$$\max(f, g)(x) = \frac{f + g + |g - f|}{2}$$
$$\max(l, m) = \frac{l + m + |m - l|}{2}$$

$$\lim_{{x}\to{a}} \max(f, g)(x) = \lim_{{x}\to{a}} \frac{f + g + |g - f|}{2}$$

$$= \frac{l + m}{2} + \lim_{{x}\to{a}} \frac{|g - f|}{2}$$

Somehow, the objective is to prove (using epsilon/delta) that

$$\lim_{x \to a} |g - f| = |m - l|$$

Let $H(x) = |g(x) - f(x)|$

$$\lim_{{x}\to{a}} H(x) = \lim_{{x}\to{a}} |g(x) - f(x)|$$

So prove that
$\displaystyle \left| |g(x) - f(x)| - Q \right| < \epsilon$ such that $|x - a| < \delta'$

And that $Q = |M - L|$

Can someone give me a hint, not the full solution?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Use the reversed triangle inequality:

$$ | |x| - |y| | \leq |x-y| $$

In particular,

$$ | |g-f| - |m-l| | \leq | g - f - m + l| = | (g-m) + (l-f)|$$

Now, you should be able to solve your problem with extremely no problem.

Comment: Hello, thanks; this was helpful, but what about |g - f|?